# statistics of detector efficiency

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

Can anybody help me with this question?

If a trigger requires hits in some minimum number of layers when the whole setup com
prises 12 detectors layers, what is the fraction of events that are recorded (as a function of
this minimum number)?

These detectors typically have an eﬃciency of 90% to generate a hit when a particle
passes through it. If you want to record the particle information at least half of the time,
what should/could your trigger requirement be?

The search for this new particle requires the detection of two particles. How should you
re-deﬁne your trigger to make sure you detect at least 50% of those?